# Геморройная кастомизация теней кнопки в Android

Tags: android

Начну с того, что в сети задавались вопросы о подобной проблеме ([раз](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47674828/how-to-add-a-blurred-drop-shadow-to-a-button), [два](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40885760/add-spreading-shadow-to-the-bottom-of-button-android), [три](https://community.commonsware.com/t/creating-a-button-with-custom-color-shadow/193)), но толковых решений я там не увидел.

У меня есть, на первый взгляд, простая задача: необходимо получить кнопку следующего вида:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Главной для меня проблемой здесь стала кастомизация тени. Т.е., как видно из рисунка, мне необходимо задать **свой цвет для тени** и, грубо говоря, радиус разброса тени.

По умолчанию везде задается серый цвет тени и настройка осуществляется с использованием свойств *elevation* и *translationZ*

В iOS данные свойства задаются из коробки, а в Android, я так понимаю, все не так то просто.

Полез гуглить и в основном встречал такие решения:

1. [Использовать **layer-list**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38353384/4512868), где один item будет тенью, а другой - базой кнопки. Подход не впечатлил тем, что с малым обилием свойств для настройки фигур, выглядит на практике это ужасно.
2. [Здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47678565/4512868) говорят о том, что нужно **"сгенерить тень"** и передать ее в *drawable layer-list*.

В принципе, подход похож на предыдущий, но с одним отличием, которое заключается в использовании дополнительных ресурсов.

Но опять же, если у меня кнопка динамически меняет размер, а к тому же работает stateListAnimator, то как правильно использовать это решение? Я пока хз...

3. Вчера увидел в доках [Create Shadows and Clip Views](https://developer.android.com/training/material/shadows-clipping), где говорится о использовании класса **ViewOutlineProvider** и переопределении метода **getOutline()** для настройки теней.

Пример:

```
  public class CustomShadow extends ViewOutlineProvider {
    
    
        int roundCorner;
    
        public ZoftinoCustomOutlineProvider(int round) {
            roundCorner = round;
        }
    
        @Override
        public void getOutline(View view, Outline outline) {
            outline.setRoundRect(0, 0, view.getWidth(), view.getHeight(), roundCorner);
        }
    }
```

Но в сети нет ни слова о изменении цвета тени при использовании данного способа (хотя может плохо искал или не там смотрел).

Получается, в Android все так "бедно" с кастомизацией теней? Как раз сегодня увидел ответ на [подобный вопрос](https://community.commonsware.com/t/creating-a-button-with-custom-color-shadow/193):

> the system tries to emulate real-world shadows, and in the real world,
> shadows do not adopt the color of the object casting the shadow.

Суть цитаты в том, что в реальном мире тень не имеет цвета (что логично). И в гугле этому подходу строго поддерживаются.

- Ребята, но все же, какой подход является лучшим при решении данной задачи?
- Кто что может подсказать?

Буду очень благодарен за ваши советы и решения.